# Windows 10: Cannot activate driver update in Windows update

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update, updates, group-policy

In Windows Update's settings, driver update has been excluded from Windows Update by a group policy.

But the respective policy was not configured. I deactivated it and now the respective entry is added to the registry
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\\ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate value 0`
but Windows Update it still says that the policy is set.

How to solve?

Comment: Have you restarted or logged out of your machine after changing the group policy?

Comment: What update? What driver?

Comment: Overall driver update option for Windows Update in system properties.

Comment: Yes, restarted the machine several times since.

Answer (score -1):

Group policy takes a little time to take effect. To enforce the group policy immediately, you should run the following command in command prompt:

**gpupdate /force**